# Twig Extension doesn't work with Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig-extension

I have created a Twig Extension to show Amounts in different currency format Like: India, USD etc..

I am doing it as follows as suggested by Symfony2 guide.

`NameSpace/AccountBundle/Extension/AccountExtension.php`

```
namespace Edu\AccountBundle\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class AccountTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'get_money_indian_format' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'get_money_indian_format'),
        );
    }

    function get_money_indian_format($amount, $suffix = 1) {
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
        if (ctype_digit($amount) ) {
            // is whole number
            // if not required any numbers after decimal use this format
            $amount = money_format('%!.0n', $amount);
        } else {
            // is not whole number
            $amount = money_format('%!i', $amount);
        }

        if (!$suffix) {
            return $amount;
        } else {
            return $amount;
        }
        return $amount;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'account_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

Registered it in `app/config/services.yml`:

```
account.twig.extension.accounttwigextension:
        class: AccountBundle\Extension\AccountTwigExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

When I am using this in twig file:
`{{ 50000 | get_money_indian_format }}`

I am getting following error:
The filter `get_money_indian_format` does not exist in `EduAccountBundle:Ledger:showLedgers.html.twig`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I copy / paste your code as it is, I get an error because your extension is

```
Edu\AccountBundle\ExtensionAccountTwigExtension
```

while in your service definition you call it as

```
AccountBundle\ExtensionAccountTwigExtension
```

if I fix the namespace, everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Its working. Can you please guide me how can I call this Extension in javascript file. in Twig its working as Like : {{ 50000 | get_money_indian_format }}. I want to call it in JS how can I

Comment: You cannot. Twig is a server-side template engine. It will render the page and send HTML to the browser. Re-coding that logic in JS library is probably quicker than any other solution.